# Speeding up (simple) text processing

Tags: python, performance, text, hex

I need to display data from two files (with equal sizes) to be able to visually compare them. For this, I made a new Tk widget consisting of four Text widgets. The first widget contains characters representing bytes from the first file, the second one contains hexadecimal values of the bytes in the left widget, and the same goes for the third and four one respective (containing data/hex values for the second file). The input data to be displayed are two bytearrays.

To fill the Text widgets, I have to process the input data (bytearrays), because

- I have to get rid of unprintable characters and some characters that caused misalignment of the respective lines in the four widgets,
- I have to fill the second/fourth widgets with hex values of the bytes, therefore I have to convert the byte values to hex numbers.

The code I used does the functionality described, and it works quite well for small files (several hundreds of kilobytes). However when I try to load bigger files (several megabytes), the time it takes to process and load the data is unacceptable (tens of seconds).

An example of my widget for displaying the data can be seen here:

[image: data-display widget]

To process the input data, I use the following code. `_ldata` and `_rdata` are bytearrays with the input data, `ldata` and `rdata` are strings to be loaded in the first and third Text widgets, `lhexdata` and `rhexdata` are strings with the hexadecimal values to be loaded in the second and fourth Text widget. `wrap` is an integer determining how many bytes will be represented on one line. The `print_chars` function replaces all the characters that caused misalignment or couldn't be selected in the Text widgets.

```py
def print_chars(self, byte):
    if (byte < 0x20 or
        (byte > 0x7E and byte < 0xB1)):
        return 0x07
    else:
        return byte
```

...

```py
ldata = "\n".join(["".join(map(chr,
                               map(self.print_chars, _ldata[i:i+wrap])))
                   for i in range(0, len(_ldata), wrap)])
rdata = "\n".join(["".join(map(chr,
                               map(self.print_chars, _rdata[i:i+wrap])))
                   for i in range(0, len(_rdata), wrap)])

lhexdata = "\n".join([" ".join(map("{0:02X}".format, _ldata[i:i+wrap]))
                      for i in range(0, len(_ldata), wrap)])
rhexdata = "\n".join([" ".join(map("{0:02X}".format, _rdata[i:i+wrap]))
                      for i in range(0, len(_rdata), wrap)])
```

I think there is a way to speed things up, but can't figure out any. Before I implemented the list comprehension, I had used for cycles for the data processing, and it was a real pain in the neck even for very short inputs. The list comprehensions vere a big improvement in performance, yet not sufficient. Thanks for any advices.

Comment: See if converting your list comprehensions to generator expressions helps. To do this, remove the square brackets in your list comprehensions, so that e.g. `'\n'.join([a for b in c])` becomes `'\n'.join(a for b in c)`. This way, you don't have to generate the entire list and store it in memory, instead accessing it lazily.

Comment: If you can read out the position of the scrollbar, you only have to format and display the part that is visible.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3 for your code? Do you need `bytes` or `unicode` strings for your GUI?

Comment: @senshin: '`'.join` on CPython uses a sequence internally. It will create one if you don't provide it I.e., join with a generator expression may be slower than join with a list. Measure it.

Comment: Why do you think the provided code snippets are the bottleneck in your program? Have you profiled your code? Have you tried hex encoding from `codecs` module or binascii.hexlify directly? What is the character encoding of your data? Have you tried bytes.translate to filter bytes?

Comment: @Jongware: You're right, that might be the best solution, but also somewhat more complicated... thank for pointing at it, if I won't be able to manage it other way, I will only display the part of the text determined by the scrollbar.
_Blckknght:_ I'm using Python 3. I don't need unicode strings (to my understanding), actually I don't care at all about the encoding since all the data I need to display is binary (WAV files), I just need to represent it as "text". _J.F.Sebastian:_ I just think the code I posted is the bottleneck (I don't do any other text processing). But maybe I could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think your first two lines can be improved by using `bytearray.translate` with an appropriate translation table rather than using your own escaping and converting system. Then you can turn it into a string with `bytearray.decode`. You still need an additional step to split the text into lines and recombine it, but I suspect that it will be faster if you've done the translation work already.

```
table = bytearray.maketrans(bytes(range(0x20))+bytes(range(0x7f, 0xb1)),
                            b"\x07"*(0x20+0xb1-0x7f))

ldata_string = _ldata.translate(table).decode("latin-1") # pick some 8-bit encoding
ldata = "\n".join(ldata_string[i:i+wrap] for i in range(0, len(ldata), wrap))
```

You can do something similar for the hex output, using the `b16encode` function from the `base64` module to convert to hex, then `decode` to make the `bytes` output into a string. The splitting and rejoining gets a bit more complicated due to the need for spaces between each pair of hex digits, but I suspect it will still be faster than encoding each byte separately.

```
import base64

lhexdata_string = base64.b16encode(_ldata).decode("ascii") # hex will always be ASCII
lhexdata = "\n".join(" ".join(hexdata_string[i+j:i+j+2] for i in range(0, 2*wrap, 2))
                     for j in range(0, len(lhexdata_string), 2*wrap))
```

Note that the code above assumes that you're using Python 3. If you're using Python 2 you'll need to change a few things (such as working around the lack of `maketrans` and not needing to `decode`).

Comment: Thanks, @Blckknght, this looks very promising! I'll try it when I return back home from work. I'm using Python 3, so this should be fine. I only need to represent binary files (WAV sound files) so the encoding doesn't matter. I'm pretty sure that doing the conversions/translations will be faster the way you suggested than doing it byte-per-byte.

Comment: @Blackknght: So I've tried to implement what you suggested, there's a huge speed-up in the first part and even the second part performs better than my code. But still it takes something like 25 sec to load two ~10MB files. There's one even worse problem I've found - memory consumption caused by the Text widgets (for the case mentioned, it consumes about 450 MB of memory). So probably the best solution would be to use the code you posted and load only the visible part of the data on the fly...